# Global Hot Key (RegisterHotKey) even form is not shown in taskbar

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that has 4 functions. When form is minimized I am showing the ***NotifyIcon*** and hiding the form in taskbar.

```
Private Sub FrmMain_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Some Text"
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Some Text"
        NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000)
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Even the program is hidden, I still want to execute the 4 functions using hot keys. I found this but it works only when I am not hiding the form in taskbar.

```
Public Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer

Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

Private Enum KeyModifier
    None = 0
    Alt = &H1
    Control = &H2
    Shift = &H4
    Winkey = &H8
End Enum

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        If m.WParam = 1001 Then
            btnFunction1.PerformClick()
        ElseIf m.WParam = 1002 Then
            btnFunction2.PerformClick()
        ElseIf m.WParam = 1003 Then
            btnFunction3.PerformClick()
        ElseIf m.WParam = 1004 Then
            btnFunction4.PerformClick()
        End If
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Private Sub FrmMain_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
    Call UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1001)
    Call UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1002)
    Call UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1003)
    Call UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1004)
End Sub

Private Sub FrmClient_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    NotifyIcon1.Text = Me.Text
    Call RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1001, KeyModifier.Alt, Keys.F1)
    Call RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1002, KeyModifier.Alt, Keys.F2)
    Call RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1003, KeyModifier.Alt, Keys.F3)
    Call RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1004, KeyModifier.Alt, Keys.F4)
End Sub
```

Is there a way to use the ***RegisterHotKey*** even the form ***ShowInTaskbar*** is set to False?

Comment: The ShowinTaskbar assignment has too many side-effects, it forces Winforms to re-create the window.  Which makes you lose the registered hotkeys.  You'll much prefer Hide() instead.  Or make it always safe by overriding OnHandleCreated() to register the hotkeys.

Comment: Thank you very much, Me.Hide() works.